# Clipping a coloured raster with polygon shp in gdalwarp changes original values, why?

Tags: raster, shapefile, gdal, clip, gdalwarp

I need to clip my raster based on a polygonal shapefile, basically leave raster values inside the polygon shape (inside red perimeter in the figure below) as shown here:

[image]

Therefore, I use:

```
gdalwarp -cutline border200millas_polygon.shp -crop_to_cutline chl.2015.04.01_2015.04.08.aqua-color.tiff out.tiff
```

This should do the trick, but it doesn't. As result I get a black raster. After checking and comparing output values from both original and clipped raster I noticed that raster values of the clipped raster were much lower that those of the original raster (e.g., STATISTICS_STDDEV in out.tiff, this one being the clipped raster):

```
Files: chl.2015.04.01_2015.04.08.aqua-color.tiff                           |    Files: out.tiff
Size is 2606, 2553                                                         |    Size is 1632, 1913
Origin = (-90.463892341650677,0.065232508032915)                           |    Origin = (-84.673288999992508,-3.392115000001818)
Pixel Size = (0.008784683301344,-0.008784616065831)                        |    Pixel Size = (0.008786027376501,-0.008785333088489)
Upper Left  ( -90.4638923,   0.0652325) ( 90d27'50.01"W,  0d 3'54.84"N)    |    Upper Left  ( -84.6732890,  -3.3921150) ( 84d40'23.84"W,  3d23'31.61"S)
Lower Left  ( -90.4638923, -22.3618923) ( 90d27'50.01"W, 22d21'42.81"S)    |    Lower Left  ( -84.6732890, -20.1984572) ( 84d40'23.84"W, 20d11'54.45"S)
Upper Right ( -67.5710077,   0.0652325) ( 67d34'15.63"W,  0d 3'54.84"N)    |    Upper Right ( -70.3344923,  -3.3921150) ( 70d20' 4.17"W,  3d23'31.61"S)
Lower Right ( -67.5710077, -22.3618923) ( 67d34'15.63"W, 22d21'42.81"S)    |    Lower Right ( -70.3344923, -20.1984572) ( 70d20' 4.17"W, 20d11'54.45"S)
Center      ( -79.0174500, -11.1483299) ( 79d 1' 2.82"W, 11d 8'53.99"S)    |    Center      ( -77.5038907, -11.7952861) ( 77d30'14.01"W, 11d47'43.03"S)
Band 1 Block=2606x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red                             |    Band 1 Block=1632x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=160.832, StdDev=122.633             |      Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=0.001, StdDev=0.479
    STATISTICS_MEAN=160.83171664774                                        |        STATISTICS_MEAN=0.00089845791949817
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=122.63291968596                                      |        STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.47865014597867
Band 2 Block=2606x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green                           |    Band 2 Block=1632x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=175.865, StdDev=108.243             |      Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=0.001, StdDev=0.488
    STATISTICS_MEAN=175.86531037027                                        |        STATISTICS_MEAN=0.00096059725510696
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=108.24324530596                                      |        STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.48752743191956
Band 3 Block=2606x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue                            |    Band 3 Block=1632x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=252.883, StdDev=20.256              |      Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=0.001, StdDev=0.540
    STATISTICS_MEAN=252.88313208935                                        |        STATISTICS_MEAN=0.0011434918975431
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=20.25592618995                                       |        STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.53998993166519
```

What would be the reason for this? Using `-dstalpha` just produces a blank output. I simply need to clip my original raster... nothing more than that. If I use gdal_rasterize instead, I can succesfully delete the polygonal shapefile from my original raster WITHOUT changing the raster original values, as explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157047/erase-shapfile-polygon-area-from-geotiff).

gdalinfo of the original raster below:

```
gdalinfo -mm -stats chl.2015.04.01_2015.04.08.aqua-color.tiff 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: chl.2015.04.01_2015.04.08.aqua-color.tiff
Size is 2606, 2553
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-90.463892341650677,0.065232508032915)
Pixel Size = (0.008784683301344,-0.008784616065831)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -90.4638923,   0.0652325) ( 90d27'50.01"W,  0d 3'54.84"N)
Lower Left  ( -90.4638923, -22.3618923) ( 90d27'50.01"W, 22d21'42.81"S)
Upper Right ( -67.5710077,   0.0652325) ( 67d34'15.63"W,  0d 3'54.84"N)
Lower Right ( -67.5710077, -22.3618923) ( 67d34'15.63"W, 22d21'42.81"S)
Center      ( -79.0174500, -11.1483299) ( 79d 1' 2.82"W, 11d 8'53.99"S)
Band 1 Block=2606x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=160.832, StdDev=122.633
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=160.83171664774
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=122.63291968596
Band 2 Block=2606x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=175.865, StdDev=108.243
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=175.86531037027
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=108.24324530596
Band 3 Block=2606x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=252.883, StdDev=20.256
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=252.88313208935
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=20.25592618995
```

Comment: That could happen if your polygon is outside the image area but I guess that you have checked that.

Comment: yeah thanks for suggesting that, I re-checked that, I will post an image of what I have as example.

Comment: Result is indeed odd. Could you prepare a zip that contains all the stuff needed for repeating your trial?

Comment: perhaps it's the GDAL version, let me try 2.0 and let you know.

Comment: ok, I tried with GDAL 2.0.0 but I got the same result, if you get this working, could you share your succesful attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took one png file from the data_dir of GeoServer. Install GeoServer and you will have the same image to play with in directory:

```
\geoserver-2.7.1\data_dir\coverages\mosaic_sample\
```

Convert png into tiff and assign projection.

```
  gdal_translate -a_srs epsg:4326 global_mosaic_6.png  tiff.tiff
    Input file size is 50, 50
    0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Then use gdalwarp:

```
gdalwarp -cutline burn.shp -crop_to_cutline tiff.tiff cut.tif
Creating output file that is 16P x 15L.
Processing input file tiff.tiff.
Warning : the source raster dataset has a SRS, but the cutline features
not.  We assume that the cutline coordinates are expressed in the destination SRS. If not, cutline results may be incorrect.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

This is the result:

[image]

Burn.shp contains one polygon:

```
POLYGON (( 10.375610236185853 39.384332051098106, 10.344426149120759 39.730475417520644, 10.87455562922735 39.92069834861771, 11.152094004106685 39.546489303836594, 10.92133175982499 39.16292503293594, 10.375610236185853 39.384332051098106 ))
```

It appeared later from the comments that the cutline shapefile "polygon border200millas_polygon.shp" contained three polygons and gdalwarp seems to accept only one geometry as a cutline. However, it can take a multipolygon which can be make from polygons for example with the QGIS function "dissolve".

Comment: AHA! perhaps it's because my polygon has 3 features? could you please add your `ogrinfo -so`to your answer?

Comment: also, you showed `gdal_rasterize` in your answer, how about `gdalwarp`? I also worked and produced the same output as with `gdal_rasterize`?

Comment: Ogrinfo is not interesting, it is just that one feature with no projection. But I guess you are right with the three polygons. Think, color white what is outside polygon A and then all that is outside polygon B -> everything colored. One 3-part MultiPolygon might work.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get a 1-feature polygon (instead of 3-features polygon), is that possible with GDAL?

Comment: it worked!! that was the issue, IT IS NEEDED A POLYGON WITH JUST 1 FEATURE!! please add the above statement to mark your answer as the answer. To get that, I used `dissolve` in QGIS, add also the way to dissolve multiparts polygon shape with GDAL.

Comment: Good to hear, despite the fact that I thought that your question was this one I answered yesterday: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163371/reverse-gdal-rasterize-i-option-does-not-work. I will edit my answer to make a bit more sense.

Comment: please add the answer also to that question, thanks again!!

Comment: gdalwarp and gdal_rasterize only accepts 1-feature polygon for this GeoTIFF editing, just to note that.

Comment: Many polygons should be OK for gdal_rasterize if -i is not used (burn outside).