# Reverse gdal_rasterize (-i option) does not work

Tags: shapefile, gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterization

When I use:

```
gdal_rasterize -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -burn 255 -burn 255 -burn 255 polygon.shp tiff.tiff
```

I get a new tiff with a white hole in it with the shape of the polygon shp. However, when I use the **`reverse`** process:

```
gdal_rasterize -i -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -burn 255 -burn 255 -burn 255 polygon.shp tiff.tiff
```

I get a blank tiff. I expect the old tiff shaped by the polygon (ie. raster values inside the polygon), instead.

Any ideas why this happens? is it possible to clip a raster with a shapefile in this way?

Comment: Are you possibly re-using the same tiff.tiff? First round burned white pixels inside the polygon and second round added white pixels outside the polygon. Burn is permanent, you can't get the original pixels back.

Comment: actually, I am using the same original tiff as input in both cases, so I should get in the 1st case get values outside the shp area (true), and the 2nd case, raster values inside the shp area (false). What would be wrong?

Comment: I tried your command with some random tiff and a polygon that I digitized and it worked as supposed. Make a zip that contains your tiff.tiff and you polygon.shp so others can have a try. Tell also your GDAL version.

Comment: that's weird then, if it works for you I think it should work here, I use GDAL 1.11.2 (released 2015/02/10). About sharing these data, these data come from a project that doesn't belong to me, for now I am not allowed to share a single minuscule byte of the data I'm working on. Don't get mad with me for this dude, just being responsible in order to avoid dealing with lawyers =D

Comment: That it works for me is just the beginning. I use GDAL 2.0, my tiff is not the same nor is my polygon which make 3 different things. Reason for the issue may be one of them, 2 of them together, or all three which makes 6 alternatives. Change one thing at a time and you will solve it.

Comment: Can you upload the polygon somewhere? Or create a new simple polygon with just three vertices and run the command?

Comment: I will try with GDAL 2.0, perhaps that's the problem. I already tried with others shapefiles and it gave the same outcome. The problem is only with `gdal_rasterize -i`.

Comment: ok, I tried with GDAL 2.0.0 but I got the same result, if you get this working, could you share your succesful attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took one png file from the data_dir of GeoServer. Install GeoServer and you will have the same image to play with in directory:

```
\geoserver-2.7.1\data_dir\coverages\mosaic_sample\
```

Convert png into tiff and assign projection.

```
  gdal_translate -a_srs epsg:4326 global_mosaic_6.png  tiff.tiff
    Input file size is 50, 50
    0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Then burn:

```
gdal_rasterize -i -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -burn 255 -burn 255 -burn 255 burn.shp tiff.tiff
Warning : the output raster dataset has a SRS, but the input vector layer SRS is  unknown. Ensure input vector has the same SRS, otherwise results might be incorrect.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Burn.shp contains one polygon:

```
POLYGON (( 10.375610236185853 39.384332051098106, 10.344426149120759 39.730475417520644, 10.87455562922735 39.92069834861771, 11.152094004106685 39.546489303836594, 10.92133175982499 39.16292503293594, 10.375610236185853 39.384332051098106 ))
```

And the result is this:

[image]

As a comparison the result without using the -i option

[image]

Comment: It is essential to note that gdalwarp and gdal_rasterize only accepts 1-feature polygon for this GeoTIFF editing, just to note that.