# Is there a proper geoprocessing term of clipping data based on the hole in donut polygons?

Tags: polygon, geoprocessing, clip, donut-polygons

This is a general question not software related. Is there a geoprocessing term used for clipping data using the holes in donuts polygons? I want the process to keep the data which are visible through the hole(s).

Comment: Please clarify your question. After the clip, would the data that is visible through the hole be deleted or what? Do you play with vector or raster data?

Comment: The data visible through the hole will be kept.

Comment: This is the default behavior, so "clipping" will suffice.

Comment: Please [edit] your question again to include what software and version you're using. You can add it as a tag as well. Screenshots also help people understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am using QGIS , FME and  ArcGIS. The question is not about about how to achieve the task. The question is what is the "name" of the processing task. If I used a software what would be the name of the tool if there is such thing? As I know clipping would clip taking in consideration the outer boundaries of the polygon and not the holes of the donut polygon.

Comment: The name could be "mask". It is not about cutting with something that does not exist (the hole in a polygon is nothing) but about hiding everything that is covered by the polygon. This question is somewhat related with how to achieve the task but it does not deal with names https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163371/reverse-gdal-rasterize-i-option-does-not-work.

Comment: @user30184 , your explanation is concise. I will use the term "masking"