# Cut hole in raster with shapefile and sample at closest edges

Tags: gdal, rasterio, nearest-neighbor, sampling, gmt

I have a raster in which I'd like to cut a "hole" with a shapefile. I have points close to the boundary, but inside the hole, and I would like to find the closest point on the edge. To give a concrete example, I have a global dataset (1' resolution) and a shapefile of the coast of Africa. My data points are locations of cities near the coast, but some of these points are not *exactly* on the coast, so I'd like to find the closest point outside the shapefile, i.e. closest point over water.

Normally, I'd use: `gdalwarp -of -GTiff -cutline Coast.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata 0.0 Data.tif Clipped_Data.tif` but this obviously only gives me what's inside the shapefile; I can't find an inverse clipping for this command.

I did some digging and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462999/how-do-i-use-rasterio-python-to-mask-a-raster-using-a-shapefile-to-set-the-rast), which allowed me to set everything inside the shapefile to 0, but when I sample using `gmt grdtrack` it just sets the values to 0 (which makes sense). Also, when I tried `crop=True, invert=True` I got: `ValueError: crop and invert cannot both be True.` So I reverted to using `crop=False, invert=True.`

So, how can I sample this raster at the closest point outside the shapefile? I think if I can get the hole to be set to NaN, I can use the -T flag in `gmt grdtrack.`

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163371/reverse-gdal-rasterize-i-option-does-not-work?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at mapproject -L option. I think it does what you want and no need to use a grid.