# Cut out parts of raster using polygons

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, clip

I am looking to cut out some areas of a large raster using polygons.

The existing clipping tools only cut the raster to the size of the polygon, but I just want to cut the areas of the polygons out of the raster.

Is there a way to invert the clipping function?

Comment: Maybe gdal_rasterize as in the not-inverted example in  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163371/reverse-gdal-rasterize-i-option-does-not-work/163524 does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Clip Raster by Mask Layer` tool. Checkout this [walkthrough](https://www.google.com/search?q=clip%20raster%20by%20mask%20layer%20qgis&rlz=1C1GCEB_enUS1046US1046&oq=clip%20raster%20by%20&aqs=chrome.2.0i512l3j69i64j69i57j0i512l3.5097j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#ip=1&kpvalbx=_pgpdZIuoM_K70PEPsaWHsA8_66).

[image]