Clip raster with mask layer, but retain the unclipped areas
I want to clip a raster with a mask layer that consist out of several polygons to remove unwanted areas. The resulting rater that I am getting retains the areas within the polygons. I want to obtain the opposite, i.e. retain the areas outside the polygons. I am using QGIS 3.34.10

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163371/reverse-gdal-rasterize-i-option-does-not-work/163524#163524. You do not want to use the -i option, but the answer contains also an example about that. Or if you want to make the masked area transparent see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157047/erase-shapefile-polygon-area-from-geotiff/157055#157055.
